# Selecting data for a span of multiple weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have two tables that look like this

```
_____________________
| UserID | UserName |  --TableName = User



________________________________________________
| UserID | DateLoggedInOn | MinutesLoggedInFor | ---TableName = SessionInfo
```

This is a report and I am supposed to allow the user to select a date range that would have no limit (span however many weeks)

Currently the report works by specifying a from date and then the report would only get the data for a week starting from the from date.

So I have a query like so

```
Declare @Day1 datetime = @FromDateTime,
     @Day2  datetime = DATEADD(DAY,1,@FromDateTime),
     @Day3 datetime = DATEADD(DAY,2,@FromDateTime), 
     @Day4 Datetime = DATEADD(DAY,3,@FromDateTime),
      @Day5 datetime = DATEADD(DAY,4,@FromDateTime),
       @Day6 datetime = DATEADD(DAY,5,@FromDateTime),
        @Day7 datetime = DATEADD(DAY,6,@FromDateTime)

SELECT UserID, username, (select sum(minutesLoggedInfor) from SessionInfo si where si.dateloggedinon  >= @Day1 and si.dateloggedinon <= @Day1 and si.UserID = u.userid) as Day1,
(select sum(minutesLoggedInfor) from SessionInfo si where si.dateloggedinon  >= @Day2 and si.dateloggedinon <= @Day2 and si.UserID = u.userid) as Day2,
(select sum(minutesLoggedInfor) from SessionInfo si where si.dateloggedinon  >= @Day3 and si.dateloggedinon <= @Day3 and si.UserID = u.userid) as Day3,
(select sum(minutesLoggedInfor) from SessionInfo si where si.dateloggedinon  >= @Day4 and si.dateloggedinon <= @Day4 and si.UserID = u.userid) as Day4,

(select sum(minutesLoggedInfor) from SessionInfo si where si.dateloggedinon  >= @Day5 and si.dateloggedinon <= @Day5 and si.UserID = u.userid) as Day5,
(select sum(minutesLoggedInfor) from SessionInfo si where si.dateloggedinon  >= @Day6 and si.dateloggedinon <= @Day6 and si.UserID = u.userid) as Day6,
(select sum(minutesLoggedInfor) from SessionInfo si where si.dateloggedinon  >= @Day7 and si.dateloggedinon <= @Day7 and si.UserID = u.userid) as Day7 from User u
```

This is pretty convoluted already and It feels wrong but it does work and gives me the data I need.
I don’t know how to get the information in multi week spans though.
So that it would return something like this

```
_________________________________________________________
| UserName | UserID | ReportingWeek      | Day1 | Day 2 | …….. 
| testuser | 5      | 5/13/18 – 5/19/18  | 120  | 240   | …….
| testuser | 5      | 5/20/18 – 5/ 26/18 | 60   | 200   | …….
```

`Reportingweek` would be a one week span for instance if the user set the `@FromDateTime = 5/13/18`
And the `@ToDateTime = 5/26/18` the report would span two weeks and the data in `Day1, Day2, Day3` .... would be only for that “`ReportingWeek`”

I’ve thought about using a while loop but I heard that it’s not best practice.

Comment: What determines `ReportingWeek`?

Comment: @TabAlleman see edits

Comment: So Reporting Week isn't based on a certain day of the week?   It's always whatever the @FromDateTime is, no matter what day of the week that is?

Comment: Come on - format

Comment: You really should be using joins here instead of subqueries. In order to offer adequate help though we need some clearer information. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @TabAlleman yes

Comment: Clean it up.  You wiped out my formatting TWICE.

Comment: where si.dateloggedinon >= atDay1 
    and si.dateloggedinon <= atDay1  ?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method is to create a "date dimension" table which is really just a list of dates, but additional information is stored with each date entry: for example:

```
DateValue: 2035-12-30
    YearDayNumber: 364
    YearNumber: 2035
    WeekDayNumber: 1
    DayName: Sunday
    YearWeekNumber: 53
```

Once you have that table, you can...

```
JOIN DateDimension d ON d.DateValue = CAST(SessionInfo.DateLoggedInOn AS DATE)
```

Now in your report you can reference the YearNumber Plus the YearWeekNumber to give the user a dropdown list of weeks. This way the dates are stored in one place so you don't need to regenerate them in your queries every time. You might even tweak the DateDimension table to include a field you need, like [YYYYWW] (201804 for the 4th week in 2018).

You can find scripts to generate a datedim table on the mighty interwebs, just be sure to get one that works with your version of SQL. Here's one I've used in the past:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Data+Warehousing/156805/